# External monitor disappears when monitors go to sleep mode

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

**Setup:**

I have Lenovo U330p laptop with Win8.1 and an external monitor (HP ZR2330w). The monitor is connected with DVI(monitor end) <-> HDMI (laptop end) cable.

**History:**

The setup has been running fine since Jan 2014, but this week I moved my desk to another room. (disconnected and powered off the monitor and connected back again in the other room) Nothing special IMO.

**Problem:**

After I physically moved the system, Windows has been able to detect and use the external monitor only occassionally.

**More insight to the problem:**

Occassionally means, Windows detects and uses the external monitor only when I uninstall the display adapter (Intel HD Graphics family) and monitor (Generic PnP Monitor). Then Windows automatically re-installs the drivers, and that makes the setup work UNTIL next time the monitors go to sleep. After that, the external screen is gone from Windows Device Manager and from both Windows Screen resolution pane, and Intel Graphic properties pane.

**My notes**

1. The screen is physically fine. It starts everytime normally and
   looks for signal. It goes to sleep when no signal is detected.
2. The cable is fine, because the screen notices when I plug on/off the
   cable. Also, the setup works after software changes (as described
   above) without touching/changing the cable physically.
3. I have installed latest drivers for the HP monitor and for the
   Display adapter (Intel).
4. The problem is not random. It happens every time systematically.
   (Win8 systematically kicks the HP out every time it gets the chance ;))

I don't know what factors could affect this, and don't have any ideas left, where to continue troubleshooting. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit**

I switched input source manually to DVI instead of Auto in the screen as suggested. That didn't help.

Comment: Make sure the dvi-hdmi cable is well plugged in both ends. On the monitor, do not leave input to auto but set it to dvi.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. I am pretty sure the issue is in seoftware rather than physical, because re-installing the drivers works. (until next time the monitor goes to sleep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after many days struggle I got the issue resolved.

**The solution was to:**

- unplug the external monitor
- uninstall all display drivers (including hidden devices)
- uninstall all monitor drivers (including hidden devices)
- reinstall display driver and Generic PnP-monitor
- plug in the external monitor

To me it seems like one of the hidden devices (previously plugged in devices, that no longer are attached to the computer) was causing the issue in one way or another, but I am not familiar enough with the hardware world to provide anything else than a sophisticated guess.